# Google Visualization append rows from multiple DataView to one DataTable

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I want to populate `data_results` which is a `DataTable` from three data views most likely a serial manner. I do not know the syntax to do this.

I've tried using `.addRow()` and `.addRows()` but can't seem to get the syntax correct when trying the final append to `data_results`.

See my simplistic example below.

Some givens:
I would like to produce a data table called `data_results`.
 
It will have 3 columns (`Final1`, `Final2`, `Final3`).
I would like to know how to take rows from `view_A`, `view_B`, and `view_C` and append them to `data_results`.

As always, your expert assistance is appreciated!

This snippet has been edited per @WhiteHat's suggestions to producce the final solution.

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['corechart', 'table', 'controls']
});

renderChart_onPageLoad();

function renderChart_onPageLoad() {
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
    drawTable();
  }); //END setOnLoadCallback
} //END function renderChart_onEvent

function drawTable() {

  var data_A = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data_A.addColumn('string', 'A1');
  data_A.addColumn('string', 'A2');
  data_A.addColumn('number', 'A3');
  data_A.addRow(['X', 'Y', 1]);

  var data_B = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data_B.addColumn('string', 'B1');
  data_B.addColumn('string', 'B2');
  data_B.addColumn('number', 'B3');
  data_B.addRow(['XX', 'YY', 2]);

  var data_C = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data_C.addColumn('string', 'C1');
  data_C.addColumn('string', 'C2');
  data_C.addColumn('number', 'C3');
  data_C.addRow(['XXX', 'YYY', 3])

  var view_A = new google.visualization.DataView(data_A);
  var view_B = new google.visualization.DataView(data_B);
  var view_C = new google.visualization.DataView(data_C);

  var data_results_join1 = google.visualization.data.join(view_A, view_B, 'full', 
  [[0, 0],[1, 1],[2, 2]], '', '');

  var data_results = google.visualization.data.join(data_results_join1, view_C, 'full', 
  [[0, 0],[1, 1],[2, 2]], '', '');

  var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('div_dashboard'));

  var categoryPicker1 = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    'controlType': 'StringFilter',
    'containerId': 'div_categoryPicker1',
    'matchType': 'any',
    'options': {
      'filterColumnIndex': 0, //Column used in control
      'ui': {
        //'label': 'Is exclude selection possible?',
        //'labelSeparator': ':',
        'labelStacking': 'vertical',
        'selectedValuesLayout': 'belowWrapping',
        'allowTyping': false,
        'allowMultiple': false,
        'allowNone': true
      }
    }
  });

  var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'Table',
    containerId: 'div_table',
    options: {
      allowHtml: true
    }
  });

  dashboard.bind([categoryPicker1], [table]);
  dashboard.draw(data_results);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id='div_dashboard'>
  <div id='div_categoryPicker1'></div><br/>
  <div id='div_table'></div>
</div>
```

When researching this task I also found this to work.

```
var data_results = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data_results.addColumn('string', 'FinalC1');
data_results.addColumn('string', 'FinalC2');
data_results.addColumn('number', 'FinalC3');

function addRowsToDataResult(sourceView, c1, c2, c3) {
   for (var i = 0; i < sourceView.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
      var col1 = sourceView.getValue(i, sourceView.getColumnIndex(c1));
      var col2 = sourceView.getValue(i, sourceView.getColumnIndex(c2));
      var col3 = sourceView.getValue(i, sourceView.getColumnIndex(c3));
      data_results.addRow([col1, col2, col3]);
   }
}
addRowsToDataResult(view_A, 'A1', 'A2', 'A3');
addRowsToDataResult(view_B, 'B1', 'B2', 'B3');
addRowsToDataResult(view_C, 'C1', 'C2', 'C3');
```

Thank you to @WhiteHat!  Cheers...

Comment: need to use the [join method](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#google_visualization_data_join) -- two times -- first to join the first two tables, and again to join the third table to the result of the first join -- [here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46293809/google-chart-with-5-columns-with-data-join-method/46299282#46299282) of how to use the join method

Comment: Hi, Can I use .join() with a DataView?

Comment: _This method joins two data tables (DataTable or DataView objects)_

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  I will try this out and let you know how it works out.  Thank you for the hint.  They are so valuable!

Comment: I got the join to work and edited my snippet above.  Could you take a look at the alternative method I finally figured out later?  Which approach would be faster regarding processing speed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment:

> need to use the join method -- two times -- first to join the first two tables, and again to join the third table to the result of the first join -- here is an example of how to use the join method – WhiteHat Oct 3 at 19:34

This was the answer.  Original post modified to reflect the suggestion. Thank you @WhiteHat